# How to write new List<CustomClass>() in Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I want to know how can we represent below c# code in the expression tree.

```
var list = new List<CustomClass>(); 
list.add(new CustomClass());
```

where CustomClass is some complex type class.

Like how an array can be initialized with Expression.NewArrayInit

Thanks

Comment: What is your *actual* question? Why do you need expression tree here?

Comment: I am working on a requirement involving expression tree and need an expression tree representation of above code snippet.

Comment: The above code snippet is a statement, not an expression!

Comment: Updated the title.

Comment: In C# you can let the compiler create your expression tree. Something like: `Expression<Func<int, int, int>> = (a,b) => a+b;`and you can inspect the tree in the debugger.

Comment: @Andrew: Only for expression-bodied lambda expressions. That's why I've converted it to a collection initializer in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that you asked is this:

```
// List<CustomClass> foo;
var listV = Expression.Variable(typeof(List<CustomClass>), "foo");

// new List<CustomClass>()
var newL = Expression.New(typeof(List<CustomClass>));

// foo = new List<CustomClass>()
var assV = Expression.Assign(listV, newL);

// new CustomClass()
var newEl = Expression.New(typeof(CustomClass));

// foo.Add(new CustomClass())
var addEl = Expression.Call(listV, "Add", null, newEl);

var be = Expression.Block(new[] { listV }, assV, addEl);
```

Note that I'm giving you a Block Expression... You can put it inside a bigger expression (or create a lambda based on it), but it isn't directly runnable (because it isn't a lambda expression)

An example of lambda expression:

```
var be = Expression.Block(new[] { listV }, assV, addEl, listV);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<CustomClass>>>(be);
var func = lambda.Compile();

List<CustomClass> res = func();
```

(note that I'm changing the `be` variable)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using two separate statements, I'd suggest using a collection initializer. At that point, you can get the compiler to build the expression tree for you, because it's a single expression:

```
Expression<Func<List<CustomClass>>> expr =
    () => new List<CustomClass> { new CustomClass() };
```

It's also more likely that tools that use expression trees (e.g. LINQ providers) will understand the tree.

The generated tree uses [`Expression.ListInitExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.listinitexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) as the sort of list-equivalent of `Expression.NewArrayInit`.

Writing the equivalent code manually is somewhat painful, but you can decompile what the compiler does with that lambda expression to do so if you really need to.